# How do I remove a directory that is not empty?

Tags: php, directory

I am trying to remove a directory with `rmdir`, but I received the 'Directory not empty' message, because it still has files in it.

What function can I use to remove a directory with all the files in it as well?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this, but see the comments at the bottom of https://www.php.net/rmdir. A number of commenters posted their own recursive directory deletion functions. You can take your pick from those.

Here's [one that looks decent](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#91797):

```
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        return unlink($dir);
    }

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
        if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        if (!deleteDirectory($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item)) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return rmdir($dir);
}
```

You could just invoke `rm -rf` if you want to keep things simple. That does make your script UNIX-only, so beware of that. If you go that route I would try something like:

```
function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    system('rm -rf -- ' . escapeshellarg($dir), $retval);
    return $retval == 0; // UNIX commands return zero on success
}
```

Comment: this is extremely dangerous, please add checks to make sure you're not deleting something important like `/` for example..

Answer (score 12):

```
function rrmdir($dir)
{
 if (is_dir($dir))
 {
  $objects = scandir($dir);

  foreach ($objects as $object)
  {
   if ($object != '.' && $object != '..')
   {
    if (filetype($dir.'/'.$object) == 'dir') {rrmdir($dir.'/'.$object);}
    else {unlink($dir.'/'.$object);}
   }
  }

  reset($objects);
  rmdir($dir);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Can't think of an easier and more efficient way to do that than this

```
function removeDir($dirname) {
    if (is_dir($dirname)) {
        $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirname, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $object) {
            if ($object->isFile()) {
                unlink($object);
            } elseif($object->isDir()) {
                rmdir($object);
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Unknown object type: '. $object->getFileName());
            }
        }
        rmdir($dirname); // Now remove myfolder
    } else {
        throw new Exception('This is not a directory');
    }
}


removeDir('./myfolder');
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always try to use system commands.

If on linux use: `rm -rf /dir`
If on windows use: `rd c:\dir /S /Q`

In the post above ([John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653771/how-do-i-remove-a-directory-that-is-not-empty/1653776#1653776)) I suppose the PHP parser will optimize that scandir in the foreach but it just seems wrong to me to have the `scandir` in the `foreach` condition statement.
You could also just do two `array_shift` commands to remove the `.` and `..` instead of always checking in the loop.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of solutions already, still another possibility with less code using PHP arrow function:

```
function rrmdir(string $directory): bool
{
    array_map(fn (string $file) => is_dir($file) ? rrmdir($file) : unlink($file), glob($directory . '/' . '*'));

    return rmdir($directory);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My case had quite a few tricky directories (names containing special characters, deep nesting, etc) and hidden files that produced "Directory not empty" errors with other suggested solutions. Since a Unix-only solution was unacceptable, I tested until I arrived at the following solution (which worked well in my case):

```
function removeDirectory($path) {
    // The preg_replace is necessary in order to traverse certain types of folder paths (such as /dir/[[dir2]]/dir3.abc#/)
    // The {,.}* with GLOB_BRACE is necessary to pull all hidden files (have to remove or get "Directory not empty" errors)
    $files = glob(preg_replace('/(\*|\?|\[)/', '[$1]', $path).'/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($file == $path.'/.' || $file == $path.'/..') { continue; } // skip special dir entries
        is_dir($file) ? removeDirectory($file) : unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($path);
    return;
}
```

Comment: To expand on the need for the preg_replace, it was necessary because some directories (with special characters) would omit subdirectories that clearly existed. I found the preg_replace note from a comment in the php.net documentation for glob(), where someone else struggled for hours with the same issue.

Comment: This is the only one that could solve my problem too +1, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here what I used:

```
function emptyDir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $scn = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($scn as $files) {
            if ($files !== '.') {
                if ($files !== '..') {
                    if (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $files)) {
                        unlink($dir . '/' . $files);
                    } else {
                        emptyDir($dir . '/' . $files);
                        rmdir($dir . '/' . $files);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$dir = 'link/to/your/dir';
emptyDir($dir);
rmdir($dir);
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#91797

Glob function doesn't return the hidden files, therefore scandir can be more useful, when trying to delete recursively a tree.

```
<?php 
public static function delTree($dir) { 
   $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following handy function:

```
/**
 * Removes directory and its contents
 *
 * @param string $path Path to the directory.
 */
function _delete_dir($path) {
  if (!is_dir($path)) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("$path must be a directory");
  }
  if (substr($path, strlen($path) - 1, 1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
    $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  }
  $files = glob($path . '*', GLOB_MARK);
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_dir($file)) {
      _delete_dir($file);
    } else {
      unlink($file);
    }
  }
  rmdir($path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't arrive to delete a folder because PHP said me it was not empty. But it was. The function by Naman was the good solution to complete mine. So this is what I use :

```
function emptyDir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $scn = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($scn as $files) {
            if ($files !== '.') {
                if ($files !== '..') {
                    if (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $files)) {
                        unlink($dir . '/' . $files);
                    } else {
                        emptyDir($dir . '/' . $files);
                        rmdir($dir . '/' . $files);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function deleteDir($dir) {

    foreach(glob($dir . '/' . '*') as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)){


            deleteDir($file);
        } else {

          unlink($file);
        }
    }
    emptyDir($dir);
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

So, to delete a directory and recursively its content :

```
deleteDir($dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

With this function, you will be able to delete any file or folder

```
function deleteDir($dirPath)
{
    if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
        if (file_exists($dirPath) !== false) {
            unlink($dirPath);
        }
        return;
    }

    if ($dirPath[strlen($dirPath) - 1] != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }

    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            deleteDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    rmdir($dirPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delTree($dir) { 
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
     foreach ($files as $file) 
       (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : @unlink("$dir/$file"); 
     return @rmdir($dir); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map('unlink', glob("your/path/*.*"));
rmdir("your/path");
```