# Codeigniter : Delete directory after deleting all files

Tags: php, directory, codeigniter-3

I want to delete a folder after deleting all the files inside it, in my codeigniter project. Lets say my folder name is `upload`, which is located near the application folder in my `ci` project.

The `upload` folder contains `Peniyal` as a sub-folder and it contains 4 images inside it. I need that 4 images to be deleted, next the sub-folder has to be deleted.`upload` folder should not be deleted.  I am hanging my mind to do it.
So far I have tried the following:-

```
$files = glob('./upload/Peniyal');//to get all file names
//am not sure whether the path is correctly given..
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files one by one
    if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file); // delete file
}
$path   = './upload/Peniyal'; 
rmdir($path);
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Any help will be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: Where and to What do you set `$foldername`

Comment: use base_url to target the specific path. if the folder name doesn't change why not just state it in your `rmdir`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am passing the folder name, in this case, it is `Peniyal` only

Comment: Then why are you not using it in the `glob` statementas well

Comment: Any problem to use ```rmdir('path_to_folder');``` in codeigniter ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i have edited my code above

Comment: @mi6crazyheart, if the folder is empty, then `rmdir` worked fine, but if the folder is not empty then it shows error

Comment: The error message is a warning: Directory not empty..!

Comment: @Keynes check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653771/how-do-i-remove-a-directory-that-is-not-empty

Comment: @mi6crazyheart, ok cool but the path which i have given above is correct?/ i am doubting it

Comment: @Keynes This ```./upload/Peniyal``` is fine. It should work. Execute & see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glob()` function matches a pattern, but you are not providing one. So if you use the pattern `*.*` the `glob` will find all files in that folder.

```
// match any file
$files = glob('./upload/Peniyal/*.*');

foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file);
}
$path   = './upload/Peniyal'; 
rmdir($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

With CodeIgnitor 4:

```
delete_files('./path/to/directory/', true);
rmdir('./path/to/directory/');
```