# Could not delete file in php using rmdir()

Tags: php

When I try to delete empty directory I got the following warnings for `on line 93` and `on line 99`:

```
Warning: unlink(/data/sites/web/xxx/www/uploads/file/2021-04-02/.nfs0000000059f70c14000017a9): Device or resource busy in /data/sites/web/xxx/www/dreq/req.php on line 93

Warning: rmdir(/data/sites/web/xxx/www/uploads/file/2021-04-02): Directory not empty in /data/sites/web/xxx/www/dreq/req.php on line 99
```

here is the delete function :

```
function rrmdir($src) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            $full = $src . '/' . $file;
            if ( is_dir($full) ) {
                rrmdir($full); // On line 93
            }
            else {
                unlink($full);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    rmdir($src); // On line 99
}
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Your question might have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653776/4050077 (Atleast for the later warning)

Comment: @Ash1271 but my function is working fine on another server. :S

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1. Check which process hold that file with `lsof -f | grep filename` to check which process hold that resource.

Issue 2. Check the manual [rmdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php), the directory must be empty.

> Attempts to remove the directory named by dirname. The directory must
> be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this. A E_WARNING
> level error will be generated on failure.

[Refer to this to has a view on where the hidden nfs file comes from](https://askubuntu.com/a/348137)

Comment: thanks for your answer. For issue 2. File is definitely empty. https://prnt.sc/1127l5r

Comment: `.nfs0000000059f70c14000017a9` is a hidden file.

Comment: how does this file come up?